# quantifier negation proof with natural deduction?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

How can I derive ∃¬()⊢¬∀()? I know that I need to derive some sort of contradiction, but what do I assume?

Comment: To prove "if P then Q" by contradiction, you start by assuming "not Q" and then prove "not P".  In both of these your "P" and "Q" themselves start with "not" so just drop those,

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
$

> How can I derive $\exists x\neg P(x) \vdash \neg \forall xP(x)$ ?

You are trying to find a proof of $\neg \forall xP(x)$. This sentence is going to be the last line of your proof. Look at $\neg \forall xP(x)$ and see what the introduction rule for its *main logical connective* is (the last connective used when building the sentence. In this case, it is a negation.
Looking at **Negation Introduction** rule schema, where $\mathcal A$ is a metavariable standing for *any* sentence:

$
\fitch{}{
 \fitch{i.\, \mathcal A}{
   j. \bot
}\\
\neg \mathcal A \ni{i-j}
}
$

We see that, assuming $\forall xP(x)$ and reaching a contradiction it is enough to justify its application. Your main proof should have roughly this skeleton:

$
\fitch{1.\, \exists x\neg P(x)}{
 \fitch{2.\, \forall x P(x)}{
   \vdots\\
   \bot
}\\
\neg \forall xP(x)
}
$

Can you continue the proof ?

EDIT: I leave full proof as reference.

$
\fitch{1.\, \exists x\neg P(x)}{
 \fitch{2.\, \forall x P(x)}{
   \fitch{3.\, \neg P(a)}{
       4. P(a) \qquad\text{$\forall \mathbf{E}$ 2}\\
          5. \bot \qquad \neg\mathbf{E}\,3,4
          }\\
6.\,\bot \qquad \exists \mathbf{E}\,1, 3-5
}\\
\neg \forall xP(x)
}
$

Comment: I continued by assuming ¬Pa and ∃¬() then got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful. I leave full proof for reference.